# renaming file before uploading it to firebase using firebase, flutter and image cropper

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage, image-cropper

Good Day. I would like to ask on how do you rename your file(image) before uploading it in your firebase storage?

I am using `image_cropper` when selecting and cropping my images. However I cannot see if it has any built-in function for renaming files.

This is my selectFile when selecting images in the local device.

```
Future selectFile() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image != null) {
        final croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
          sourcePath: image.path,
          aspectRatio: const CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
          compressQuality: 100,
          maxWidth: 450,
          maxHeight: 450,
          compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
          aspectRatioPresets: [CropAspectRatioPreset.square],
        );
        setState(() {
          imagePath = croppedImage!.path;
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }
```

and this is my uploadFile function

```
Future uploadFile() async {
    final path = 'products/${imagePath.split("/").last}';
    
    final file = File(imagePath);

    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);
    uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

    final snapshot = await uploadTask!.whenComplete(() {});

    final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    var url = urlDownload.toString();
    print(url);
```

the `imagePath` is my selected image.

and every time I upload it on my firebase storage it renames itself as
`image_cropper_1234567890.jpg` and I just want to display the image as `1234567890`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
final path = 'products/${imagePath.split("_").last}';
```

Comment: Hello, It is working and would like to ask what was the difference between ``split("/")`` vs ``split("_")``` ? I'd appreciate your explanation.

Comment: Your `imagePath` might look something like this: `"path/path/image_cropper_123456789.jpg"`. So i would split by `"_"` to get only the number part of the filepath and use this in the firebase-storage `path`.